# C# Unity Photon проблема спавна

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда игрок входит на сервер работает следуйшый код, когда входит первый игрок все нормально, когда входит второй спавнится* 3 `player(Clone);`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.IO;

public class gameManag : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    // public Text chat;
    public GameObject PlayerPf;
    public GameObject CameraPf;
    public Managmant NAME;
    private PhotonView play;
    private Vector3[] spawn = new []{new Vector3(0f,19f,65f),new Vector3(80f,19f,65f),new Vector3(80f,-24f,65f),new Vector3(0f,-24f,65f)};
    private void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs","player"),spawn[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,3)],Quaternion.identity);
        // GameObject.Find("player(Clone)").name = PhotonNetwork.NickName;
        // PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs","Cam"),new Vector3(GameObject.Find(PhotonNetwork.NickName).transform.position.x,GameObject.Find(PhotonNetwork.NickName).transform.position.y,-30f),Quaternion.identity);
        // GameObject.Find("Cam(Clone)").name = PhotonNetwork.NickName+"cam";
    }
    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPl)
    {
        // PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs","player"),spawn[Random.Range(0,3)],Quaternion.identity);
        // GameObject.Find("player(Clone)").name = PhotonNetwork.NickName;
        // PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs","Cam"),new Vector3(GameObject.Find(PhotonNetwork.NickName).transform.position.x,GameObject.Find(PhotonNetwork.NickName).transform.position.y,-30f),Quaternion.identity);
        // GameObject.Find("Cam(Clone)").name = PhotonNetwork.NickName+"cam";
    }
}
```

Comment: Переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос более понятным образом.

Comment: @CrazyElf что не понятно? код для спавна, когда игрок вгодит создается empty с етим скриптом , а скрипт сванит игрока , и когда входит первий игрок все норм   , входит втарой спавнивается + 3 player(Clone).***** извини за ошибки, я не руский

Comment: Что значит ` + 3 player(Clone)`?

Comment: плюус три player  палучается в ерархии 4 player(Clone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш скрипт `gameManag` выполняется на всех инстансах игры. В момент когда заходит 2-ой игрок выполняются `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` у первого игрока; `Start` и `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` у второго игрока. Что бы с этим справится есть несколько вариантов

1. Удалить `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` и писать класс `gameManag` с расчетом что он будет выполняться у всех игроков

или, предпочтительнее

2. Делать проверку в классе `gameManag` `IsMasterClient`, например

```
   private void Start()
   {
       Spawn();
   }

    private override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPl)
    {
       Spawn();
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
       if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

       PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs","player"), spawn[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,3)], Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

3. В принципе, ещё можно использовать обычный `Instantiate`, а не `Pthoton`

PS: обратите также внимание, что в вашем случаи игроки могут заспауниться в одном и том же месте.

PPS: вот чертовки классный русскоязычный туториал по Photon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqxzrk-pl-8